# How to prove $\exp(-\frac{i}{2} \theta (e.J)) = I \cos(\frac{\theta}{2})- i( e.J) \sin(\frac{\theta}{2}) $

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, angular-momentum

The following identity

$(\boldsymbol a\cdot\boldsymbol J)(\boldsymbol b\cdot\boldsymbol J) = (\boldsymbol a\cdot\boldsymbol b) I + (\boldsymbol a×\boldsymbol b)\cdot\boldsymbol J$$\tag1$

is used to prove

$\exp(-\frac{i}{2} \theta\boldsymbol (e\cdot \boldsymbol J)) = I \cos(\frac{\theta}{2})-\mathrm i(\boldsymbol e\cdot \boldsymbol J) \sin(\frac{\theta}{2}) $$\tag2$

which is used in quantum mechanics for rotation operators,

where $\boldsymbol a,\boldsymbol b,\boldsymbol e \in \mathbb{R}^3, e$ is a unit vector, $I$ is the identity matrix and $ \boldsymbol J = (\boldsymbol J_1, \boldsymbol J_2, \boldsymbol J_3) $ where $\boldsymbol J_1, \boldsymbol J_2, \boldsymbol J_3 $ are 3×3 matrices.

But I didn't understand how identity 1 is true? Can it be verified using any other coordinate geometry relations? And how this identity helps to transform the the above exponential equation?

Comment: I got the equation and info that it can be verified using the given identity from a Caltech lecture note. http://www.hep.caltech.edu/~fcp/physics/quantumMechanics/angularMomentum/angularMomentum.pdf

Comment: Is this about proving the equation in the title or proving the first equation in the post using the equation in the title?

Comment: The one in the title is just a property of Pauli matrices.

Comment: @Mauricio I want to prove Eq.(2), but also wanted to understand how we have Eq.(1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll continue with $\boldsymbol \sigma=(\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3)$
instead of $\boldsymbol J$
to represent the Pauli matrices.

---

To prove Eq(1):

The commutators and anti-commutators between Pauli matrices are

$$
[\sigma_i,\sigma_j]=2\mathrm i\varepsilon_{ijk}\sigma_k,\quad 
\{\sigma_i,\sigma_j\}=2\delta_{ij}.
$$
Adding up the two equations and dividing by 2 gives
$$
\sigma_i\sigma_j=\delta_{ij}+\mathrm i\varepsilon_{ijk} \sigma_k.
$$
The product of a vector $\boldsymbol a\in\mathbb C^3$ and the Pauli vector $\boldsymbol \sigma$ is
defined as
$$
\boldsymbol a\cdot\boldsymbol \sigma=a_i\sigma_i.
$$
So
$$
\begin{aligned}
(\boldsymbol a\cdot\boldsymbol \sigma)
(\boldsymbol b\cdot\boldsymbol \sigma)
&=a_jb_k\sigma_j\sigma_k\\
&=a_jb_k(\delta_{jk}+\mathrm i\varepsilon_{jki}\sigma_i)\\
&=a_kb_k+\mathrm i\varepsilon_{ijk}a_jb_k\sigma_i\\
&=\boldsymbol a\cdot\boldsymbol b+\mathrm i(\boldsymbol a\times \boldsymbol b)\cdot\boldsymbol \sigma.
\end{aligned}
$$

---

To prove Eq(2):

As stated in the lecture, let $\boldsymbol a=\boldsymbol b=\boldsymbol e$, we get
$$
(\boldsymbol e\cdot \boldsymbol \sigma)^2=I.
$$
The exponential of a matrix is defined as the Tylor series
$$
\begin{aligned}
\exp\left(-\mathrm i\frac{\theta}{2}\boldsymbol e\cdot\boldsymbol \sigma\right)
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty
\frac{(-\mathrm i\theta)^n}{2^nn!}
\left(\boldsymbol e\cdot\boldsymbol \sigma\right)^n\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty
\frac{(-\mathrm i\theta)^{2k}}{2^{2k}(2k)!}
\left(\boldsymbol e\cdot\boldsymbol \sigma\right)^{2k}
-
\mathrm i\left(\boldsymbol e\cdot\boldsymbol \sigma\right)
\sum_{k=0}^\infty
\frac{\mathrm i^{2k}\theta^{2k+1}}{2^{2k+1}(2k+1)!}
\left(\boldsymbol e\cdot\boldsymbol \sigma\right)^{2k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty
\frac{(-)^k}{(2k)!}\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)^{2k}
-\mathrm i
\left(\boldsymbol e\cdot\boldsymbol \sigma\right)
\sum_{k=0}^\infty
\frac{(-)^k}{(2k+1)!}\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)^{2k+1}\\
&=\cos\frac\theta 2
-\mathrm i(\boldsymbol e\cdot\boldsymbol \sigma)
\sin\frac{\theta}{2}.
\end{aligned}
$$
In the second line, the series is split into two parts, containing even and odd terms respectively.

Comment: There is an identity matrix missing in the first term of final equation.

Comment: @Igris Yes, but when there is no ambiguity, a number is considered as the identity multiplied by a scalar.

Comment: if we replace the Pauli spin matrix $\sigma$ by general angular momentum operator J, where there there is an additional $\frac{\hbar}{2}$ term in front of these Pauli spin matrices, we won't be able to take out that $\hbar$ terms from inside sine and cosine, right?

Comment: Substituting $\boldsymbol \sigma=\frac2\hbar\boldsymbol J$ into Eq.1, you'll get $(\boldsymbol e\cdot\boldsymbol J)^2= \frac{\hbar^2}4$, and the $\hbar$'s are eliminated in the series, except an extral $\frac2\hbar$ factor in front of sine in the final result. You can as well substitute $\boldsymbol \sigma=\frac2\hbar\boldsymbol J$ into the final line to get the result.

Comment: how do we eliminate the $\frac{\hbar^2}{4}$. That term in the taylor expansion has a power to it.

Comment: @Igris $(\boldsymbol e\cdot \boldsymbol \sigma)^2=\frac4{\hbar^2}(\boldsymbol e\cdot\boldsymbol J)^2=I$. The substituted formula doesn't change anything. Just have a try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138971/discussion-between-igris-and-luessiaw).